# Xcode 7.0.1 - cannot run application cocoa error - 102

Tags: cocoa, xcode7, osx-yosemite

I've located an oddity:
On  10.10.5 I can open xcode,  start a new project,  iOS single view application,  arbitrary product name,  Swift as the language and all other values default,  build and run the application.

As an admin,  this executed as expected.

As a non admin user however it competes the build and then fails to run with the error "The operation couldn't be competed.  (Cocoa error - 102.)"

I've checked permissions on everything and all looks well.
Can anyone point me to a fix?

Comment: Being an admin doesn't actually give you elevated privilege does it?  It just means you *can* get them if required.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't inherently give permissions.  What I imagine is that somewhere the non admin account is passively shutout of a file or folder.  Nothing shows in the log files and this has been replicated across several machines and user accounts.  I cannot provision admin access to general user accounts however.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing all my extensions, doing a full clean, re-adding the extensions in the build-phases tab and then running the app again.